# Unable to save data to custom field on Account Details Grid

Tags: c#, acumatica

I have a custom button that updates a custom boolean field on selected rows. The field is being updated, but the changes are not committing to the database. The error below is being thrown on the last line gltran.Persist()

```
public class AccountByPeriodEnq_Extension : PXGraphExtension<AccountByPeriodEnq>
{
    public PXAction<AccountByPeriodFilter> Recon;

    [PXButton(CommitChanges = true)]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Reconcile")]
    protected void recon()
    {
        PXCache gltran = Base.Caches[typeof(GLTran)];
        foreach (GLTran tran in gltran.Updated)
        {
            if (tran.Selected == true)
            {
                GLTranExt gltranEx = tran.GetExtension<GLTranExt>();
                if (gltranEx.UsrRecon == true) gltranEx.UsrRecon = false;
                else gltranEx.UsrRecon = true;
                gltran.Update(tran);
                gltran.Persist(PXDBOperation.Update);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Error:

> {"Error: 'AmtReleasedClearedDr' cannot be empty."}

Stack:

> "   at PX.Data.PXDefaultAttribute.RowPersisting(PXCache sender, PXRowPersistingEventArgs e)\r\n   at PX.Data.PXCache.OnRowPersisting(Object item, PXDBOperation operation)\r\n   at PX.Data.PXCache`1.PersistInserted(Object row)\r\n   at PX.Data.PXCache`1.Persist(PXDBOperation operation)\r\n   at PX.Data.PXRowPersisting.Invoke(PXCache sender, PXRowPersistingEventArgs e)\r\n   at PX.Data.PXCache.OnRowPersisting(Object item, PXDBOperation operation)\r\n   at PX.Data.PXCache`1.PersistUpdated(Object row)\r\n   at PX.Objects.CA.CashTranIDAttribute.RowPersisting(PXCache sender, PXRowPersistingEventArgs e) in F:\\Bld2\\AC-FULL61U8-JOB1\\sources\\WebSites\\Pure\\PX.Objects\\CA\\Descriptor\\CashTranIDAttribute.cs:line 828\r\n   at PX.Objects.GL.GLCashTranIDAttribute.RowPersisting(PXCache sender, PXRowPersistingEventArgs e) in F:\\Bld2\\AC-FULL61U8-JOB1\\sources\\WebSites\\Pure\\PX.Objects\\GL\\Descriptor\\Attribute.cs:line 3462\r\n   at PX.Data.PXCache.OnRowPersisting(Object item, PXDBOperation operation)\r\n   at PX.Data.PXCache`1.PersistUpdated(Object row)\r\n   at PX.Data.PXCache`1.Persist(PXDBOperation operation)\r\n   at PX.Objects.GL.AccountByPeriodEnq_Extension.recon() in c:\Program Files (x86)\Acumatica ERP\AcumaticaERP\App_Code\Caches\AccountByPeriodEnq.cs:line 43"

### -----------------------------------------------------------------------

**Working Code (Thank you Patrick):**

```
public class AccountByPeriodEnq_Extension:PXGraphExtension<AccountByPeriodEnq>
{
    public PXAction<AccountByPeriodFilter> Recon;

    [PXButton(CommitChanges = true)]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Reconcile")]
    protected void recon()
    {
        PXCache gltran = Base.Caches[typeof(GLTran)];
        foreach (GLTran tran in gltran.Updated)
        {
            if (tran.Selected == true)
            {
                GLTranExt glTranEx = tran.GetExtension<GLTranExt>();
                var recon = (glTranEx.UsrRecon == true) ? false : true;

                PXDatabase.Update<GLTran>(
                    new PXDataFieldAssign<GLTranExt.usrRecon>(recon),
                    new PXDataFieldRestrict<GLTran.batchNbr>(tran.BatchNbr),
                    new PXDataFieldRestrict<GLTran.lineNbr>(tran.LineNbr)
                );                 
            }
        }           
    }        
}
```

Comment: Did you try performing a .Persisting() without parameters?

Comment: I'm not seeing that method. It looks like the error is being caused by the OnRowPersisting event. Is there a way to override it?

Comment: Looking at your code again, I don't think you need to call a persisting at all, unless you want to save the entire record. If that's the case, then you should call a Base.Actions.PressSave(). Otherwise, I'd remove the gltran.Persist(PXDBOperation.Update);. Your call to Update should be enough to have the changes stored in Cache pre-record save.

Comment: I'm getting the same error using PressSave.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might try something like this code in your button.  This will update without triggering other events.

```
PXDatabase.Update<GLTran>(
   new PXDataFieldAssign<GLTranExtension.UsrRecon >(bool_var),
   new PXDataFieldRestrict<GLTran.batchnbr>(tran.batchnbr),
   new PXDataFieldRestrict<GLTran.lineNbr>(tran.LineNbr)
);
```

Comment: How would I use this with a custom field? >The type name 'UsrRecon' does not exist in the type 'PX.Objects.GL.GLTran'